# Zend_Gdata_Spreadsheets_ListQuery() issue : Zend_Gdata_App_HttpException: Expected response code 200, got 400 Invalid request URI

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, google-sheets, gdata

I'm trying to create a web application that provide to the user a way to extract data from a desired worksheet.

### The Background

1. The user connect himself to my application using the Oauth2 after having selected one of his Google's account.
2. My application gets each one of his spreadsheets (using *getSpreadsheetFeed()*'s method from the *ZendGdataSpreadsheets*' class) and display them.
3. The user choose one of his spreadsheet.
4. My application gets the id of the selected spreadsheet in order to retrieve each worksheets of the spreadsheet. In the same time, it display all these retrieved worksheets.
5. The user choose one of the available worksheet.
6. **My application has now a spreadsheet's id and a worksheet's id to work on it. But an error occurs when I try to use *getListFeed()*'s method.**

---

### The Related Code

```
    $query = new Zend_Gdata_Spreadsheets_ListQuery();
    $query->setSpreadsheetKey($ssKey);
    $query->setWorksheetId($wsKey);
    $listFeed = $ssService->getListFeed($query); // Where the error occurs
```

I gets both my *$ssKey* and my *$wsKey* from a $_POST.

---

### The Errors

```
    Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Gdata_App_HttpException' with message ' in *****\Zend\Gdata\App.php on line 714

    Zend_Gdata_App_HttpException: Expected response code 200, got 400 Invalid request URI in *****\Zend\Gdata\App.php on line 714
```

---

### Extra Informations

**var_dump($query)**

```
    object(Zend_Gdata_Spreadsheets_ListQuery)[11]
      protected '_defaultFeedUri' => string 'https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list' (length=42)
      protected '_visibility' => string 'private' (length=7)
      protected '_projection' => string 'full' (length=4)
      protected '_spreadsheetKey' => string 'https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/spreadsheets/*KEY*' (length=74)
      protected '_worksheetId' => string 'https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/worksheets/*KEY*/private/full/od6' (length=89)
      protected '_rowId' => null
      protected '_params' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      protected '_url' => null
      protected '_category' => null
```

**$query->getQueryUrl()**

```
    https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/spreadsheets/*KEY*/https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/worksheets/*KEY*/private/full/od6/private/full
```

---

If you need any further informations, let me know.

Thanks you in advance,

Cedric.